# How can load balancing be handled in Hadoop mapreduce?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed

How can load balancing be handled in Hadoop mapreduce? I am writing a distributed application in which the server distributes jobs to worker nodes based on a benchmark test, memory available, number of CPU cores, CPU usage, number of GPUs available / usage? I am not very experienced with mapreduce and have read some documentation on apache's website but am still not sure how to go about and solve this problem. Can I do the benchmark calculation and get this all of this information and then by an algorithm to dynamically split up the input?

Thank you!

Comment: I think this link might help:
http://bradhedlund.com/2011/09/10/understanding-hadoop-clusters-and-the-network/

Comment: Thanks was very informative about mapreduce, but we will not be handling large amounts of data per se, the article only mentions balancing storage. I am wanting to know if I can balance the load dynamically based on the capabilities of the slave node: a bench mark that will be run, CPU speed/number of cores/CPU usage, num GPUs/usage, available main memory.

Answer (score 1):

Performance of MapReduce systems strongly depends on an even data distribution. 
Apache MapReduce frameworks  use a simplistic approach to distribute the work load and assign the same number of clusters to each reducer.

The load imbalance, which raises the processing time, is even ampliﬁed by the high runtime complexities of the reducer tasks. An adaptive load balancing strategy is required to address the problem of estimating the cost of the tasks that are distributed to the reducers based on a given cost model.

Answer (score 0):

"MapReduce is a programming model and an associated implementation for processing and generating large data sets" extract of the abstract of MapReduce paper.

As you said it in comments, it seems your project is not data intensive but computing intensive, thus I think MapReduce is not the tool you need to use.